# To split SQL query result into groups

Tags: sql, oracle

I have approx. 200k records in the table.
I want to split them into 10 groups, 20,000 in each group. I'm aware of ntile function. It will split records in to 10 groups where group no. starts from 1. i.e. 1,2,3...9,10.
Perfect!

Question is,
How can I have the same grouping with different set of numbers. E.g. instead of 1,2,3...9,10;  say 214,215,216 ...223,224.
Can we have it with ntile function Or is there any other method/function to split result set into groups?

As mentioned above/in a problem definition, I tried and I'm getting number from 1 to 10.
I'm trying to divide result-set into any consecutive 10 numbers/groups e.g. 267 to 277 or 437 to 447

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the expected output for that sample data; an English explanation (not code) of the logic that is required to transform the sample data to the output. At the moment it is unclear why the numbers 214-224 are relevant.

Comment: The question you've asked can be ansered very simply - just add an offset to the value returned by ntile() but I suspect that's not what you actually want. We need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible in this way:

```
SELECT 
    salesman_id, 
    sales,
    213 + -- your starting point here is
    NTILE(10) OVER(
        ORDER BY x DESC
    ) quartile
FROM 
    your_table_name ;
```